# How to reads image file directly from script in python?

Tags: python, path

When i read image file, i have to created it in cmd `python my_script.py e:\facerec\data\at`. Then it worked well. Below is my script

```
''' my_script.py '''
import sys
# append tinyfacerec to module search path
sys.path.append("..")
# import numpy and matplotlib colormaps
import numpy as np
# import tinyfacerec modules
from tinyfacerec.subspace import pca
from tinyfacerec.util import read_images

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "USAGE: example_eigenfaces.py </path/to/images>"
        sys.exit()

    # read images
    [X,y] = read_images(sys.argv[1])
```

But when i changed the script like this

```
  ''' my_script.py '''
import sys
# append tinyfacerec to module search path
sys.path.append("..")
# import numpy and matplotlib colormaps
import numpy as np
# import tinyfacerec modules
from tinyfacerec.subspace import pca
from tinyfacerec.util import read_images

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # read images
    [X,y] = read_images('e:\facerec\data\at')
```

I got this error
`need more than 1 value to unpack`

How to reads file directly from my script? Thank you

Comment: your path of image file is correct? i can't see image file extention?

Comment: I were uploading my directory here [link](http://oi58.tinypic.com/30rlmk9.jpg)

Comment: are you use `'e:\\face\\face1'` Instead of `'e:\face\face1'`?

Comment: I used this `e:\facerec\data\at`. I have edited my post. The error is seems before

Comment: use `\\` instand of `\`

Comment: may i know how to use it?

Comment: It seems that you have hard coded a different path `'e:\facerec\data\at'` than `'e:\face\face1'` further more because you are using backslash I advise to use raw string `r'e:\face\face1'`

Comment: I've been using windows @Vivian De Smedt, so i used it to read path directory

Comment: It's running when i'm using `e:\\facerec\\data\\at`. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is related to the use of backslash. The `'\f'` string is equivalent to `'\x0c'` aka form feed. But what you probably want is `'\\f'` that you can also write `r'\f'`.

If you replace in your script the following section your problem will probably be solved.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # read images
    [X,y] = read_images(r'e:\facerec\data\at')
```

Comment: It's running well when i'm using e:\\facerec\\data\\at. Thank you all